# no method with name='getCodeCacheDir' after implementing Firebase

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase

Recently I added Firebase to Unity project. Project is built perfectly but when I run project on Android device it crashes and exception is :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getCodeCacheDir'     
signature='()Ljava/io/File;' in class Landroid/app/Activity; at   
java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method) at  
java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:421) at 
java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331) at 
java.lang.System.load(System.java:565) at 
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) at 
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) at 
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source) at 
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at 
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Answer (score 1):

This line says it all:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getCodeCacheDir'

It is very likely that *Google Play Services* is not updated. You have to update it to the latest *Google Play Services* and this problem should go away.